# How to write a gstreamer plugin that has RGB buffer as input?

Tags: c, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing, decoding

I'm learning about gstreamer. The tutorials [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c) are great. However, I couldn't find how to do something as simple as making it read an RGB buffer from memory.

How do I insert an RGB buffer consumer into the pipeline? This would be useful for integrating USB cameras. Many have SDKs that decode to RGB buffers but then additional work needs to be done to integrate it into gstreamer.

Comment: Terminology! So you want to write a `source` element? You will create and pass around `GstBuffer`s. Which just can carry any payload. What is in these buffers exactly is described by negotiating `caps` between elements.

Comment: Also https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/index.html?gi-language=c is a good entry point for developing elements (its quite a different topic than regular GStreamer applications).

Comment: If you want just to pass some buffer into a pipeline, check out the `appsrc` element.